# Render empty tags in SXA

Tags: sxa

For VariantTemplate, I want the tag to be empty and just want the value from the template.
Even when selecting the empty tag, it renders a div in the site.
I also changed the standard values of VariantTemplate to change to an empty tag. Still doesn't work.
Is there a way to get empty tags?
I'm using SXA version 1.8
[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can't do this out of the box. You need to patch the `Sitecore.XA.Foundation.RenderingVariants.Pipelines.RenderVariantField.RenderTemplate.RenderField` method. Out of the box, this method does this:

```
public override void RenderField(RenderVariantFieldArgs args)
{
  Sitecore.XA.Foundation.RenderingVariants.Fields.VariantTemplate variantField = args.VariantField as Sitecore.XA.Foundation.RenderingVariants.Fields.VariantTemplate;
  if (variantField == null)
    return;
  HtmlGenericControl tag = new HtmlGenericControl(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(variantField.Tag) ? "div" : variantField.Tag);
  this.AddClass(tag, variantField.CssClass);
  this.AddWrapperDataAttributes((RenderingVariantFieldBase) variantField, args, tag);
  Dictionary<string, object> parameters = new Dictionary<string, object>()
  {
    {
      "item",
      (object) args.Item
    }
  };
  if (args.Parameters != null && args.Parameters.ContainsKey("geospatial"))
    parameters.Add("geospatial", args.Parameters["geospatial"]);
  tag.InnerHtml = ServiceLocator.ServiceProvider.GetService<ITemplateRenderer>().ExecuteTemplate(args.Item.Name, variantField.Template, parameters);
  args.ResultControl = (Control) tag;
  args.Result = this.RenderControl(args.ResultControl);
}
```

Notice this line:

```
HtmlGenericControl tag = new HtmlGenericControl(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(variantField.Tag) ? "div" : variantField.Tag);
```

So if the tag field is empty, it defaults to a div. In my solution I replaced that method with:

```
public class RenderTemplate : Sitecore.XA.Foundation.RenderingVariants.Pipelines.RenderVariantField.RenderTemplate
{
    public override void RenderField(RenderVariantFieldArgs args)
    {
        var variantField = args.VariantField as VariantTemplate;
        if (variantField == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(variantField.Tag))
        {
            base.RenderField(args);
        }
        else
        {
            var templateRenderer = ServiceLocator.ServiceProvider.GetService<ITemplateRenderer>();
            var parameters = new Dictionary<string, object>() { { "item", args.Item } };
            if (args.Parameters != null && args.Parameters.ContainsKey("geospatial"))
            {
                parameters.Add("geospatial", args.Parameters["geospatial"]);
            }

            // There is no surrounding html tag, so just render the resulting string from the template.
            args.Result = templateRenderer.ExecuteTemplate(args.Item.Name, variantField.Template, parameters);
        }
    }
}
```

Now, it keeps the empty tag field and just renders the contents out. Just patch that method instead of the default one, like this:

```
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/" xmlns:set="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/set/">
    <sitecore>
        <pipelines>
            <renderVariantField>
                <processor type="MyNamespace.RenderTemplate, MyAssembly" resolve="true"
                        patch:instead="processor[@type='Sitecore.XA.Foundation.RenderingVariants.Pipelines.RenderVariantField.RenderTemplate, Sitecore.XA.Foundation.RenderingVariants']" />
            </renderVariantField>
        </pipelines>
    </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

For this patch file, its important that you place it in a `z.Folder` so that it patches after all the SXA include files that are in the `App_Config/Include` folder, otherwise the patch will fail.

Answer (score 1):

@Dawid Rutkowski, checked in SXA 1.9 - `div` tag is still there as fallback for template.
@Richard Seal, approach you offered (skip Control creation) works fine except cases when *VariantTemplate* is **under** *VariantSection* - then template is not rendered at all - see in SXA 1.9 `Sitecore.XA.Foundation.RenderingVariants.Pipelines.RenderVariantField.RenderSection` :

```
base.PipelineManager.Run("renderVariantField", renderVariantFieldArg);
if (renderVariantFieldArg.ResultControl == null)
{
    continue;
}
control.Controls.Add(renderVariantFieldArg.ResultControl);
```

as Control is not created for VariantTemplate, Result is not added to a page.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I remember from the code in 1.8 this is how it works. We had fallback there, so even if you will leave this field empty it will render `div` anyway.

Good news is that we've changed this behaviour. In 1.9 you will be able to skip the wrapping tag (I'm not sure if this is already in 1.8.1).